# In REDCap, Is there a way for outside users to add an instance to a record from a survey link, based off the selection of a "name" field?

Tags: sql, dynamicquery, redcap

For the purposes of my REDCap project, mosts users will only have access to the build through a survey link. The survey is to track staff members on a team, so supervisors will use the survey link to add, edit, or remove staff members.

Is there a way for people to choose a name of the staff member they would like to edit, and based off of this, rather than it being a new record, register the survey as a repeating instance of the staff name they chose?

I was able to create a dynamic query of an updatable list of staff names, but if someone chooses the staff name it will create a new record, despite me having a repeatable instrument.

I would like `[staff]` to be the unique field which records are connected by.